# How to: Update live sites theme from version control repo via plugin or library?

Tags: theme-development, plugin-recommendation, hosting, git

Maybe someone knows how i could update my live sites theme from a version control<sup>*)</sup> project repository.

Point is that it's really time consuming if you got your theme hosted with version control *(as an open source project)*, have a live site that uses the theme and maybe also make it available else where. Normally that means half an hour until you got everything running after you wrote an update/commited something.

I've seen it once that a server got a "live" update via a git project, but so far couldn't find out how this would be done.

Nice would be if there's a plugin out there that does this already. Libraries or similar are also ok.

<sup>*) The Q is about Github, Bitbucket, etc. and it also doesn't matter if the solution is git or svn based.</sup>

Thank you!

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean. As a silly example, you can do a git pull from the server!

Comment: @anu: Sure, if you have shell access. You could even automate it, using github's POST service.

Comment: Ehm, kinda not in scope (now that I think about it)?..

Comment: @Rarst You can convert to CW if you want.

Comment: Unless you want to put this into context of WP specifics (folder structure, etc) I am more inclined to close as off topic.

Comment: @Rarst I'm talking about "themes", which imho already states that it's meant in wp context. I appretiate every help rewriting it to be more wp specific.

Comment: Yeah, but "theme" here is essentially "arbitrary set of PHP files that happen to be in WordPress folder". Integrating github in WordPress functionality (like theme/plugin updater) would be specific, but just a small subset of your question and not necessarily best approach.

Comment: @Rarst I edited the Q and added [tag:plugin-recommendation].

Answer (score 6):

I use a script called [git-ftp](https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp), which simply uses FTP to push changes from a git repo onto a server.

Answer (score 3):

I just made a tutorial on how to do a site update directly from github using a cloud server ( PHP application), in this demo I am using Engine Yard, but ther are other apps, it's pretty crazy what you can do these days.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZEiFi4thDI&feature=feedlik

Answer (score 3):

We are using Mercurial via Bitbucket, but same logic applies:

1. Clone repository to server.
2. Protect it from being web-accessed.
3. Create PHP script that will issue pull and update command to the repo.
4. Set up Bitbucket to ping PHP script on commit.

This is not quite "proper" deployment scheme, but it hugely streamlines workflow on development servers that need to fetch multiple different components from multiple repos.